# Sequelize Association getting data like JSON

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have simplified my problem with two tables as coconut and coconut_lists. Coconut table stores the specifications of coconut and coconut_lists store which seller has the coconut. For each time, a relation is created between seller and coconut it's inserted into coconut_lists table.

I have tried to use through keyword with attributes, setting different relations HasMany, HasOne, BelongsToMany.

Coconut_List

```
import { Column, DataType, Model, Table, ForeignKey, BelongsTo } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import Coconut from './coconut';


@Table({
  modelName: 'cononuts_list',
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
})
export default class CoconutList extends Model<CoconutList> {
  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
  })
  public id: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  public sellerId: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => coconut)
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  public coconutId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Coconut, 'coconutId')
  public coconut: Coconut;


}
```

Coconut

```
import { Column, DataType, Model, Table, HasMany } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import CoconutList from './coconutList';


@Table({
  modelName: 'coconuts',
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
})
export default class Coconut extends Model<Coconut> {
  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
  })
  public id: number;

  @HasMany(() => CoconutList, 'id')
  public coconutList: CoconutList[];

  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  public weight: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  public count: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.FLOAT,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  public size: number;
}
```

The query :

```
const coconutsBySeller = await CoconutList.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Coconut,
        attributes: ['weight', 'size', 'count'],
      },
    ],
    attributes: ['sellerId'],
  });
```

Output of code is as follows :

```
[
  {
    "sellerId": "f3ff90d8-ed8e-42c9-9c7b-d607111a359e",
    "coconut": {
      "weight": 100,
      "count": 6,
      "size": 11,
    }
  },
  {
    "sellerId": "f3ff90d8-ed8e-42c9-9c7b-d607111a359e",
    "coconut": {
      "weight": 200,
      "count": 12,
      "size": 20,
    }
  },
  {
    "sellerId": "ffffaaaa-ed8e-42c9-9c7b-d607111a359e",
    "coconut": {
      "weight": 300,
      "count": 18,
      "size": 50,
    }
  },
  {
    "sellerId": "ffffaaaa-ed8e-42c9-9c7b-d607111a359e",
    "coconut": {
      "weight": 100,
      "count": 6,
      "size": 11,
    }
  }
]
```

Instead I want to get

```
[
  {
    "sellerId": "f3ff90d8-ed8e-42c9-9c7b-d607111a359e",
    [{
      "weight": 100,
      "count": 6,
      "size": 11,
    },
    {
      "weight": 200,
      "count": 12,
      "size": 20,
    }]
  },
  {
    "sellerId": "ffffaaaa-ed8e-42c9-9c7b-d607111a359e",
    [{
      "weight": 300,
      "count": 18,
      "size": 50,
},   
    {
      "weight": 100,
      "count": 6,
      "size": 11,
    }
  ]
]
```

In addition to the format of data, I also wonder if it's possible to get min_max values of the weight, count, size fields of coconuts assigned to the seller using Sequelize within the above query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for grouping by the seller:

```
const coconutsBySeller = await CoconutList.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Coconut,
        attributes: ['weight', 'size', 'count'],
      },
    ],
    attributes: ['sellerId'],
    group: ['sellerId']
  });
```

Comment: It returns only one object instead multiple.